# jquery crossdomain image upload (works good on same domain, doesn't get result on crossdomain)

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I've a jquery iframe based upload script to allow my clients to change images in their website.
Work's good, but I want to have a crossdomain solution, so when i update my code, all of my clients get updated also.

the files are actualy uploaded, but I can't read the content of iframe, even he is there, I can see it, but can't read it.

I know it is a security issue, but It's my server, I'm just allowing the upload of .jpg files.

How can I solve this, all my domains are in the same ip, hosted in a vps server.

some code

```
div_browser = '<iframe id="iframe_uploads" name="iframe_uploads" frameborder="0" align="center"';
    div_browser += '"></iframe>';
    modal_uploads(div_browser);
    function modal_uploads(data) {
        var modal = '<div id="modal">';
        modal += data;
        modal += '</div>';
        $("#gestor").append(modal);
        //
        var id = "#modal";
        var winH = $("#gestor").height();
        var winW = $("#gestor").width();
        $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
        $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);
        $(id).fadeIn(2000);
    }
$("#iframe_uploads").load(function() {
        var resposta = document.getElementById('iframe_uploads').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
        var erro = resposta.split('|');
        var medidas = erro[1];
        if(erro[0] == "ok") {
            nome.val('pics/'+$('#ficheiro').val());
            var wh = medidas.split('=');
            $("#"+nome[0].id+"_width").val(wh[0]);
            $("#"+nome[0].id+"_height").val(wh[1]);
            $('#modal').animate({opacity: 1.0},1000).fadeOut('fast');
            $('#modal').remove();
        } else {
            $('#modal').html = resposta;
        }
    });
```

doing this, I've one iframe waiting for the result of upload process.
I can see in that upload was succeded, since iframe content is there, something like "ok|44=55", but I'm unhable of manipulate that data...

Thanks, hope you can help me

Comment: When posting code on stackoverflow.com, please post the minimum necessary (critical) code, so your problem is identified better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is not possible to do without full server control.

I managed to do it using php ftp upload functions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that even if your servers have the same ip, it's a cross-domain issue for the client (cause they have different domains).

However, as you own the server, there are some workarounds you can do:

1) Use just one domain (the most obvious, but the most probable is you can't)

2) Use proxy code in your server (to communicate one domain with the other, so client sees only 1 domain)

To help you better, i'd like to know: 1) Which technology are you using in your server? (php, java, asp.net, etc) 2) Could you post your form code (mainly action/urls)

Hope this helps

Comment: hello, using php as server side script, easy just like this 'code'<form id='form_uploads' enctype='multipart/form-data' action="<?php echo dominio."/php/upload.php?accao=upload"; ?>" method='POST' target='iframe_uploads'>'code'

Comment: Ok. Can you do some of the alternatives I posted? Could you please supply the domain where your page is running? and the full domain of the form action?


PS: Are you from Brazil?

Comment: de portugal :-) não quero usar um só domínio, por questões de actualização. A parte do proxy code não percebi muito bem... desculpe, não quero postar os domínios, como disse isto pode ser uma grande falha de segurança e não vejo a vantagem de os divulgar

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can make this work with a following trick:

Suppose you have a form at site.com, and upload handler at uploads.com, then you do as you do but upload handler after doing its work instead of sending response redirects to for example:

`http://site.com/redirect/?status=OK&width=44&height=55`

or

`http://site.com/redirect/?status=Some+error+message`

and `http://site.com/redirect/` just sends you an empty page.

Then in your load handler you parse iframes `document.location.href` and get your response. In some browsers `load` event will be fired twice (redirect response + final empty response), you should just ignore permission denied errors.